# For the sake of security, what's the benefit of the id token provided by OIDC? What if id token is stolen?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, impersonation

I have read a lot about OIDC and OAuth2, I know the id token is mainly used for the client to know who the user is and whether the user is still online currently.

Furthermore, Id token can prevent a class of impersonation attacks [You can find more details in [this](https://oauth.net/articles/authentication/) article].

But what if the id token is stolen? Can the attacker uses the id token to impersonate a user?

In our project, we just ensure https besides the OIDC. What else security consideration should I take to mitigate the impersonation attacks?

Answer (score 5):

The goal or purpose of OIDC is not to be more secure than OAuth2, and this kind of comparison doesn't make sense. They solve different problems.

Let's start with OAuth2. In very short and somewhat simplified, OAuth2 solves the problem when a website holds data of a user, and that user wants to grant access to some of their data to another website. Say you have a Facebook account, but want to allow my application to access some of your data on Facebook, or for a more concrete example, you want to allow my awesomeapp.com app to post a link to your Facebook wall. For this, my website redirects you to Facebook, you log in, get an access token, and send that access token back to my website so that I can use it in your name to get what you allowed me to.

Note that there is one thing missing. I have no idea who you are. I just had an access token, with which I can do stuff, but I don't have *identity* info about you. Sure, this can be abused in different ways, the access token can hold your email address or whatever, but it's limited, the size matters, and there is no standard way.

At least not until OIDC comes in the picture. OIDC provides the identity element.

The purpose of the ID token is to provide identity info, to tell me *claims* about who you are. It may claim what your email address is, what security groups you are in, which company you work for, or anything else. Also it may be used to download more claims, in case they don't all fit in the actual token (see *userinfo*). These claims come from the Identity Provider, say Facebook, which my application then has to trust of course, i.e. I will believe whatever Facebook tells me about you.

This is all possible with pure OAuth2, but there is no standard, well known way to do so (or well, it is OIDC :) ). You could invent and implement something yourself, but these things are more complicated than they may first seem to be. That's why OIDC was invented, so you don't have to. But after all, OIDC is just a way to use OAuth2 to provide identity. In the end, it's just an extended OAuth2 if you like.

As for what security considerations you need to take into account - this part of your question is way too broad and can't be answered unfortunately. Security is a very complex topic.

Comment: Thanks Gabor. I think to provide identity info is one purpose of the ID token, another  purpose may be  prevent impersonation attacks as the access token doesn't provide identity info. However, I still don't get what if the Id token is stolen? Can the attacker use the stolen Id token?

Comment: I have updated the question to be more specific, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really a security purist so my additions to Gabor's points are from a more practical viewpoint, as someone responsible for building well architected UIs and APIs:

- An id token represents proof of authentication to a UI
- An id token is **NEVER** used by APIs, which must use access tokens instead
- An id token is the only type of token a UI should ever read, and it is mandated to have a JWT format
- For Web UI logins an id token provides extra security, since it enables the UI to validate tokens and protect against some types of token substitution attack - so yes - OIDC is more secure
- An id token is sometimes needed in order for logout to work

You should **ALWAYS** use a certified security library that does this type of work for you, rather than reading tokens directly in your own code.